# vaadin + spring boot: Cannot forward to error page for request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-status-code-404, vaadin, http-status-code-500

By single view application vaadin 7.7.7, spring-boot 1.5 i check uri fragment https:/tld/#!category-name-1 from user and if the category exist show items and if not

```
VaadinService.getCurrentResponse().sendError(404, "page not found!");
```

but i got error after update spring-boot 1.5 and vaadin 7.7.7 (with embeded tomcat):

```
Cannot forward to error page for request [/vaadinServlet/UIDL/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

How can i send http error pages from vaadin to user?

ErrorPageCutomizer.java

```
@Component
public class ErrorPageCutomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/error/404"));
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/error/500"));
    }
}
```

RestController.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ErrorHandlingController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH + "/404")
    public String error404() {
        return "<div style='font-weight:bold; margin-top:200px; text-align:center; font-size:160%;'>Page not found...<br><a href=\"https://tld\">to home</a></div>";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH + "/500")
    public String error500() {
        return "<div style='font-weight:bold; margin-top:200px; text-align:center; font-size:160%;'>500 Internal server error...</div>";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soliution was:

```
 @Configuration
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Bean
    public ErrorPageFilter errorPageFilter() {
        return new ErrorPageFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean disableSpringBootErrorFilter(ErrorPageFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working for Vaadin 8.0.5 & Spring boot 1.5.3

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the SystemMessagesProvider. In that provider you could define an errorUrl for a variety of errors:

```
public class YourServlet extends VaadinServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException
    {
        super.servletInitialized();

        getService().setSystemMessagesProvider(new SystemMessagesProvider()
        {
            @Override
            public SystemMessages getSystemMessages(SystemMessagesInfo systemMessagesInfo)
            {
                final CustomizedSystemMessages c = new CustomizedSystemMessages();
                final String errorUrl = "<url to errorpage>";
                c.setSessionExpiredURL(errorUrl);
                c.setSessionExpiredNotificationEnabled(false);

                c.setAuthenticationErrorURL(errorUrl);
                c.setAuthenticationErrorNotificationEnabled(false);

                c.setCommunicationErrorURL(errorUrl);
                c.setCommunicationErrorNotificationEnabled(false);

                c.setCookiesDisabledURL(errorUrl);
                c.setCookiesDisabledNotificationEnabled(false);

                c.setInternalErrorURL(errorUrl);
                c.setInternalErrorNotificationEnabled(false);

                c.setSessionExpiredURL(errorUrl);
                c.setSessionExpiredNotificationEnabled(false);
                return c;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The question was 'How can I send http error pages from vaadin to user?'. Not 'How can I send error pages with Spring'. And my suggestion is exactly this. I'd appreciate an explanation why my answer was downgraded.

Comment: if i send: VaadinService.getCurrentResponse().sendError(404, "page not found!");
got following error on console:
"Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false"

customizing sys msg is not was i mean